# C++ not reports error or warning with data type mismatch

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Does C++ automatically cast data type based on function definition? I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_value(int i) {
    cout << "Here is an integer: " << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    float f = 3.3;
    print_value(i);
    print_value(f);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile (QT creator, CMake). There is no error. And the output of the program is:

```
Here is an integer: 5
Here is an integer: 3
```

I expect there will be compile error such as: data type mismatch, since I'm passing a float number to a function which only takes integer. But There is no compile error.

For sure I'm missing something, but couldn't find out why. Thank you.

Comment: There are implicit conversions that C++ will do for numbers and some other types https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Make a delete honeypot `print_value` template, then specialize the one you want.  `template <typename T> void print_value(T) = delete;`.

Comment: Your compiler may have a warning level or other option that emits warnings for type conversions and you may have another option that turns warnings into errors.

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/nWavxe

Comment: Like @g23 said, the compiler will do it for you unless you tell it not to.  Look at https://www.godbolt.org/z/8enGG6 - see where it assigns 5 to edi and then for the second call it assigns 3 to edi?  It knew the function took an int parameter so an int was passed.  If you turn off optimizations https://www.godbolt.org/z/bfq6q9 you can see the cvttss2si opcode that truncates the value in the floating point register xmm0 to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a function with a parameter `T2` using a value of type `T1` an implicit conversion is performed, if possible. All arithmetic types in C++ can be implicitly converted to one-another, although not always without loss of precision.
Also see [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

The particular conversion which takes place in your case is a truncating conversion:

> #### Floating-Integral conversions
>
> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined (even when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply).  [...}

(See [Floating-Integral conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions))

In practice you should enable compiler warnings (`-Wconversion`) to spot the conversions you don't want to happen. Explicitly converting with `static_cast` makes it clear that you intended for a conversion to take place.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now.I did add `-Wall` in the compile flag. 

I thought `all` would include everything. Apparently I was wrong. I learned two things in one question.

Answer (score 0):

The code is unambiguous. There is only one thing it could mean -- convert the `float` to an `int`. So the code compiles successfully.